# ContentValues vs SQLiteStatement

Tags: java, android

Which is better to use when inserting data into table? I know that SQLiteStatement works faster than ContentValues with a huge amount of rows, but I do not think that    every application has so big databases. Which class do you use to insert data in 2019?Maybe you noticed some other differences between them.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is 2019 **if you want to use SQLite use [ROOM](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)**, which provides abstraction over SQLite.

Very Easy to use.

Part of Architecture components(will work with components like [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata))

Comment: Thank you, I will check